# Generic way to parse excel files

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have a requirement to parse the excel file and create the list of objects from that. TO do the same we are using the There are `org.apache.poi` to read the excel file and we are able to get the required details, currently we are getting the cell value based on the index and set it to the object field. But we believe it is not a good way to get the values based on the index and we should find a generic way to successfully parse the excel file in case some columns are added or removed so that we don't have to do much effort on code. I came across [this article](https://roytuts.com/generic-way-of-reading-excel-file-using-apache-poi/) which almost fulfills the requirements but used the reflection methods which we are not allowed to use. Is there any possible way to parse the excel file without using the cell index where we don't have to put much effort if the format of the excel file gets changed?

```
public List<DTO> jsonConverter(Workbook workbook, Sheet sheet, String filename)
      throws ParseException {
    List<DTO> listOfDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
    Row row;
    for (int index = 1; index <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); index++) {
      row = sheet.getRow(index);
      if (row != null) {
        DTO dto = new DTO();
        dto.setFieldX(
            getCellValueAsStringBasedOnCellType(
                workbook, row.getCell(0, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)));
        dto.setFieldY(
            getCellValueAsStringBasedOnCellType(
                workbook, row.getCell(1, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)));
        listOfDTOs.add(dto);
      }
    }
    return listOfDTOs;
  }

public String getCellValueAsStringBasedOnCellType(Workbook workbook, Cell cell) {
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
      FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
      return formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
    }
    return formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
  }
```

Comment: Make the First row a header containing the name of the column.

Comment: the formula evaluator is not needed - excel cells have a cached copy of the formula result - POI doesn't implement all the excel functions - so forcing a re-evaluation of the formula could easily result in errors or incorrect values - just use formatter.formatCellValue(cell) even if the cell is formula type

Comment: excel is not a good way to exchange data - CSV, JSON, Parquet, Avro, Protobuf - there are an endless list of better formats to exchange data in - and most of these formats have good lib support for binding the exchange data format to Java classes (or equivalent)

Comment: @PJ Fanning: "just use formatter.formatCellValue(cell) even if the cell is formula type": Without `FormulaEvaluator` `DataFormatter.formatCellValue` will return the formula string rather than the calculated value.

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks for correcting my mistake - I've logged https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65730

Comment: @PJ Fanning: Well, best case would be, if `cellType` is `cellType.FORMULA` and no `FormulaEvaluator` is given, then first try getting the cell value and if not present return the formula string. But sometimes `apache poi` itself stores value `0` when formula is not yet evaluated. That's worse because `0` **is** a value and should not stand for "not available".

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It's fairly simple:

### The setup

Read the first row in the excel file, treat it as columns, and read every cell as a string.

Store these in an array.

Now you can turn any index into the column name, simply using the expression `headers[idx]`.

Thus, for any given cell, you know the header name. Now you need to translate this knowledge into the right call. Given that you're in column, say, E (`i == 4`), the header value is `header[4]` which is, say, `Address`, then you want to take the string (`"Address"`) and turn that into the right call. You end up needing to invoke:

```
String cellValue = getCellValueAsStringBasedOnCellType(workbook, row.getCell(1, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)));

dto.setFieldAddress(cellValue);
```

Everything in that code snippet is the same for any value of that string, *except* the `setFieldAddress` name.

So, we need to turn the string `"Address"` into the act of invoking setFieldAddress.

### The solution

`java.util.function` and hashmaps to the rescue!

This is a way to store in a variable the concept of taking a dto instance and setting the Address field:

```
BiConsumer<DTO, String> setAddress = (dto, value) -> dto.setFieldAddress(value);
```

or even simpler:

```
BiConsumer<DTO, String> setAddress = DTO::setFieldAddress;
```

These snippets do the same thing: They don't set an address; they are a recipe for *how* that is done, and you store the concept of setting an address on a DTO in a variable so you can run it later and as many times as you want. This is generally called a 'closure' a 'lambda'.

We can store these things in a map:

```
Map<String, BiConsumer<DTO, String>> dtoSetters = new HashMap<>();
dtoSetters.put("Address", DTO::setFieldAddress);
```

And then we can just figure it out:

```
int colIdx = ...;
String headerName = header[colIdx];
var setter = dtoSetters.get(headerName);
if (setter == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected column header in excel sheet: " + headerName);

String cellValue = getCellValueAsStringBasedOnCellType(workbook, row.getCell(1, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)));

setter.apply(dto, cellValue);
```

Thus, make that map (once, at system boot, e.g. with static initializers), replace your `dto.setFieldX` code with the above, and voila.